# yii pagination with array

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I am trying to do yii pagination and followed this [example](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25901-pagination-solution-simple-and-complex-ways/). How ever it does not seem to work for me. I want to paginate an array of string values. Following is what I have:

**CONTROLLER**

```
$location = $this->location($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$files = $this->getFiles("/data/scan/invoice");
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1);
$item_count = count($files);        
$pages = new CPagination($item_count);
$pages->setPageSize(Yii::app()->params['listPerPage']);
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();

$pages->applyLimit($criteria);  // the trick is here!       

$this->render('index',array(
            "location"=>$location,
            "files"=>$files,
            'item_count'=>$item_count,              
            'page_size'=>Yii::app()->params['listPerPage'],
            'pages'=>$pages
));
```

**VIEW**

```
<div id="main">
    <table>
        <?php foreach($files as $q): ?>

        <form>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan=2>
                    <div>
                        <object data="<?php echo '/data/scan/invoice/'.$q; ?>" type="application/pdf">
                            <p>
                                It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser. No
                                biggie... you can <a href="#">click
                                    here to download the PDF file.</a>
                            </p>
                        </object>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><input id="lognumber" type="text" /> <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="search()"/> 
                <div style="height:40px;width:100%;">
                </div>
                    <br> <input type="button" value="Save" /> 
                    <br> <input type="button"value="Delete" /> <br>
                    <div id="lookup"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="300px"><?php //echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,'Jumping','partial/my_pagination_control.phtml'); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>

<?


$this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
        'currentPage'=>$pages->getCurrentPage(),
        'itemCount'=>$item_count,
        'pageSize'=>$page_size,
        'maxButtonCount'=>5,
        //'nextPageLabel'=>'My text >',
        'header'=>'',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pages'),
));
```

The array of string values are  filepaths which will be used to display pdf files in object viewer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you apply the limit on an empty CDbCriteria:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$pages->applyLimit($criteria);  // the trick is here!
```

And then you never use `$criteria`. In your example they apply the limit on `$criteria` and then they use it to fetch the data so when yii is fetching the data it knows that it'll be paginated:

```
$this->render('index',array(
                        'model'=> ModelNameX::model()->findAll($criteria), 
        ));
```

To do what you want you'll need to use `CArrayDataProvider` for the data that need to be paginated.

```
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($files);
$dataProvider->setPagination($pages);
```

And in your view you'll need to call

```
$dataProvider->getData() //will return a list of arrays.
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you use [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) (which creates a data provider based on an array), it's a tiny little leap to using [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView), and you can let Yii handle the table generation, sorting, pagination, layout, etc.

Comment: Hum you also can use it with a CListView letting him do what he was doing in the foreach loop by calling another view.

Comment: I have used dataprovider but how would i implement this for my use?

Comment: I have used dataprovider. however the `CLinkPager` comes out in bullet form?

Comment: How can I turn the result into tabular format if i wanted to ?